# CSV Helper Mapper: How to map list property during CSV write

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I'm trying to generate CSV file based on Model where one of the properties is list.
So, my goal is to specify some list of properties and generate fields and values based on this properties. As an example, result can be like:

| Attribute:Brand | Attribute:Brand | Attribute:Size | Attribute:Brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test Value1 | Test Value2 | Test Value3 | Test Value4 |

I was trying and fail with anonymous objects or model objects.

[image]

Basically, there are two challenges:

1. Split list property to the fields. I see there is Converter method, but it returns string
2. Generate header name depends on specified. I see there is a Name method can handle alternative names.

Any idea/advise of how it can be resolved? What will be better to use anonymous object or model?

Note: I don't need to read it at all. I just need to save it.

[image]

Comment: I could be mistaken, however, there are other formats you can output to that will naturally work with lists. Are you stuck on the CSV format? I am confident you could do it, however, if you need this, I would suggest a format that fits your needs and save yourself a bunch of unnecessary work. Just a thought.

Comment: Unfortunately, the goal is to generate csv file. So, I need to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you could do it.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<ProductCsvModel>
    {
        new ProductCsvModel
        {
            DirectCosts = 1.1M,
            Attributes = new List<dynamic>
            {
                new { Brand = "Test1" },
                new { Season = "Test2" },
                new { Brand = "Test3" },
                new { Custom = "Test4" }
            }
        }
    };
    
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var first = records.First();
        
        csv.WriteHeader<ProductCsvModel>();
        
        foreach (var item in first.Attributes)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                csv.WriteField("Attribute:" + property.Name);
            }
        }
        
        csv.NextRecord();
        
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            csv.WriteRecord(record);
            
            foreach (var item in record.Attributes)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(property.GetValue(item));
                }               
            }

            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
}

public class ProductCsvModel
{
    public decimal DirectCosts { get; set; }
    public List<dynamic> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks a lot!